# Vuejs 3: Why is my custom dialog not appearing when the user tries to leave the page without saving data?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, onbeforeunload, customdialog

How to display custom dialog in vuejs 3 when user try to leave page without saving data ?

I try to use onBeforeunload in mounted hook but my dialog don't appear
Here is my code:

```
onMounted(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = "";
    wantToLeavePage.value = true;
    console.log("want to leave page", wantToLeavePage.value);
  };
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
});
```

My dialog should appear when wantToLeavePage is true

Comment: In the code you shared, `wantToLeavePage` is not defined and, when run, will generate an error telling you exactly that. Secondly, if `wantToLeavePage` would be a `ref`, your code will not make the dialog show up when you change the value of `wantToLeavePage`. It will make the dialog show up when the user triggers `beforeunload` event on the `window` object (e.g: when they try to leave or refresh the page). But changing `wantToLeavePage`'s `value` will not result in the dialog to be shown or hidden.

Comment: Here's [a playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-borg-ny01uh?file=/src/App.vue) which should make things more clear. **Note** it is unclear what is the problem you're trying to solve. Are you having difficulties showing the dialog or are you attempting to change the displayed message of the dialog? Heads up: it is not possible to change the message, it's coming from browser and the page has no control over it. You might be able to change the language by setting the browser's locale to a different one, but you still have no control over the actual message being displayed.